# Recursive feature elimination combined with nested (leave one group out) cross-validation in scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to do a binary classification for 30 groups of subjects having 230 samples by 150 features. I founded it very hard to implement especially when doing feature selection, parameters tunning through nested leave one group out cross-validation and report the accuracy using two classifiers the SVM and random forest and to see which features been selected.

I'm new to this and I'm sure the following code is not correct:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut        
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE    
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV    
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score   
from sklearn.svm import SVC    
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier      


X= the data (230 samples * 150 features)      
y= [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1..]   
groups = [1,2...30] 


param_grid = [{'estimator__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0]}]   
inner_cross_validation = LeaveOneGroupOut().split(X, y, groups)   
outer_cross_validation = LeaveOneGroupOut().split(X, y, groups)    
estimator = SVC(kernel="linear")   
selector = RFE(estimator, step=1)    
grid_search = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid, cv=inner_cross_validation)   
grid_search.fit(X, y)   
scores = cross_val_score(grid_search, X, y,cv=outer_cross_validation)
```

I don't know where to set "the random forest classifier" in the above because I want to compare the accuracies between SVM and random forest.

Thank you very much for reading and hope that someone can help me.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should call the tree in the same way that you call the SVM

```
#your libraries
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

#....
estimator = SVC(kernel="linear") 
estimator2 = DecisionTreeClassifier( ...parameters here...)


selector = RFE(estimator, step=1)
selector2 = RFE(estimator2, step=1)


grid_search = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid, cv=inner_cross_validation)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(selector2, ..greed for the tree here.., cv=inner_cross_validation)
```

Please note that this procedure will lead to two different set of selected features: one for the SVM and one for the Decision Tree

Comment: when I use this code: 
   
param_grid = [{'estimator__C': [0.01]}]       

inner_cross_validation = LeaveOneGroupOut().split(X_Nor, y, groups)       

outer_cross_validation = LeaveOneGroupOut().split(X_Nor, y, groups)        

estimator = SVC(kernel="linear")       

selector = RFE(estimator, step=1)        

grid_search = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid, cv=inner_cross_validation)       

grid_search.fit(X_Nor, y)      
 
scores = cross_val_score(grid_search, X_Nor, y,cv=outer_cross_validation)    

I got the error:    

TypeError: can't pickle generator objects

Comment: Sorry @James I just saw the comment. Can you please tell me which is the line generating the error?

Comment: The error generate by the last line of the code and it said " can't pickle generator objects"

Comment: I didn't realized earlier but what you are asking here is another problem. According to stackoverflow rules you should post it as a separated question. It will be easier to answer sine the code will be easier to read. If my answer satisfied your original question, please accept it